# How to remove a character at the end of each line in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I would like to remove comma `,` at the end of each line in my file. How can I do it other than using substring function in `awk`?

Sample Input:

```
        SUPPLIER_PROC_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
        BTCH_NBR INTEGER NOT NULL,
        RX_BTCH_SUPPLIER_SEQ_NBR INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CORRN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        RX_CNT BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        DATA_TYP_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        DATA_PD_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        CYC_DT DATE NOT NULL,
        BASE_DT DATE NOT NULL,
        DATA_LOAD_DT DATE NOT NULL,
        DATA_DT DATE NOT NULL,
        SUPPLIER_DATA_SRC_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        RX_CHNL_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        MP_IMS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        MP_LOC_ID NUMERIC(3,0),
        MP_IMS_ID_ACTN_CD BYTEINT NOT NULL,
        NPI_ID BIGINT,
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/,$//' file > file.nocomma
```

and to remove whatever last character:

```
sed 's/.$//' file > file.nolast
```

Comment: Rather than sending the output to a newfile you can also append the -i switch to sed to write i to 'file'

Comment: @ubuntu101010101 Indeed but using this option might trigger a `sed` error instead. The question is tagged Unix. Using a non POSIX GNUism would make my suggestion not portable.

Answer (score 87):

Try doing this :

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-1)}' file.txt
```

This is more generic than just removing the final comma but any last character

If you'd want to only remove the last comma with awk :

```
awk '{sub(/,$/,""); print}' file.txt
```

Comment: I was just trying something like this,  and for some reason you need a `length($0)` without the `-1`... it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me either. But whatever, it's bash, as long as it works.

Answer (score 7):

An `awk` code based on `RS`.

```
awk '1' RS=',\n' file
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=",\n"}1' file
```

This last example will be valid for **any char** before *newline*:

```
awk '1' RS='.\n' file
```

**Note**: *dot* `.` matches any character except *line breaks*.

**Explanation**

`awk` allows us to use different record (line) `regex` separators, we just need to include the comma before the *line break* (or `dot` for *any* char) in the one used for the `input`, the `RS`.

**Note**:  what that `1` means?

*Short answer*, It's just a shortcut to avoid using the `print` statement.
In `awk` when a condition gets matched the default action is to print the input line, example:

```
$ echo "test" |awk '1'
test
```

That's because `1` will be always **true**, so this expression is equivalent to:

```
$ echo "test"|awk '1==1'
test
$ echo "test"|awk '{if (1==1){print}}'
test
```

**Documentation**

*Check* [Record Splitting with Standard awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/awk-split-records.html#awk-split-records) and [Output Separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html#Output-Separators).

Comment: Upvoting this because I was able to pipe the output of `ls` into the second statement and strip a particular file extension. Some of the other answers might have worked for this as well, but this one was easier for me to read while still staying nice and short.

Answer (score 0):

This Perl code removes commas at the end of the line:

```
perl -pe 's/,$//' file > file.nocomma
```

This variation still works if there is whitespace after the comma:

```
perl -lpe 's/,\s*$//' file > file.nocomma
```

This variation edits the file in-place:

```
perl -i -lpe 's/,\s*$//' file
```

This variation edits the file in-place, and makes a backup `file.bak`:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 's/,\s*$//' file
```