# How to remove pipe at end of each line of a .dat file in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have a .dat file similar to example below:

```
1|sam  |test|
2|eric |test|
3|james|test|
```

any idea how I can remove the pipe '|' at the end of the line and save it?

I have tried `sed 's/.$//' file > file.nolast`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a character at the end of each line in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840953/how-to-remove-a-character-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/.$//g' file > file.nolast`

`g` in the end of `sed` command forgotten.